# how to read an excel file on google app engine

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, csv

Generally I work with CSV files but for this project I need to support XLS too. Does anyone have experience reading XLS files on GAE with Python?

2 possible alternatives I am considering:

- [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)
- [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs)

Comment: What specifically do you need to do with them?

Comment: I need to read the text from a few of the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) saves you the network round-trip implied by the use of Google Docs; if you don't need to keep the document stored (which would be a substantial plus for Google Docs), this might incline you towards xlrd.  I believe they're both high-quality.

However, for both speed and accuracy of "translation", there's really no alternative to benchmarking them both on a range of files reflecting *your* specific needs and interests.

Comment: @Manjoor, I suggest you open a separate question with the proper tags, so that Java-on-GAE will see it and respond.

Comment: I have done but did not got any reply.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202009/how-to-read-an-excel-file-on-google-app-engine-java

Comment: @Manjoor, then maybe the answer is "no" -- after all, it's always hard to give a "there is no such library" response with certainty, but if nobody knows of one, then maybe there isn't.