# how to read an excel file on google app engine

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine

I am looking for java alternative for python library. Here is the question
[how to read an excel file on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360010/how-to-read-an-excel-file-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to use in GAE but there is Apache POI Library to work with MS Office files

Comment: Apache POI doesn't work in the App Engine http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the blog posting ['How to generate excel files on GAE?'](http://www.z80.fr/2010/03/30/google-app-engine/how-to-generate-excel-files-on-google-app-engine/).  It discusses using the [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) library in GAE.  JExcelAPI supports both writing and read of Excel documents, and doesn't seem to have a dependency on the JRE classes that cause issues with the use of Apache POI.

Comment: Note that the link 404's today. If it's still down when you read this, use the web archive link here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100910011509/http://www.z80.fr/2010/03/30/google-app-engine/how-to-generate-excel-files-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: @jason is this works now or is there any alternative.I cant download jars.

Comment: @jason I was able to do this but JExcelAPI works only for exell 2003 or before.Is three any library supporting appengine which help us read newer excell ones .

Comment: @user2217535 I haven't worked on this in a few years, but the following post might be useful -http://amithmit.blogspot.com/2010/04/this-poi-hack-on-google-appengine-lets.html