# Replacing text in Google document from Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a document (native Google doc) in Google Drive that I need to update from my Java app. What I did so far is to download the doc as html

```
String downloadUrl = doc.getExportLinks().get("text/html");
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory()
                           .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl))
                           .execute();
String contents = IOUtils.toString(resp.getContent());
```

Then I update the contents in the `String` object and send the update to Drive:

```
ByteArrayContent mediaContent = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/html", contents);
service.files().update(doc.getId(), doc, mediaContent).execute();
```

This works fine for very simple documents. But if the document contains an image, it disappears. The `src` attribute of the `img` tag is empty.

Does Google provide some other methods of updating the contents of a Google Document? Is there an API similar to the [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)?

Comment: try having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546070/does-google-app-engine-support-apache-poi

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood, thanks for the link but I am not trying to update Microsoft Document but native Google Drive document.

Comment: sorry I was focusing on the Apache POI part

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Google doesn't provide a fine-grained REST API for manipulating the contents of a Google Docs document. [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) provides a service that does this, but it may be difficult to integrate it into your Java application.